# jquery plugin to expand an image in a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is more of a search question rather than seeking an answer. You can put in on Hold or Close it, Choice is all Yours,.

My Question is: Looking for jquery Plugin which has the option of expanding the image opened within a thickbox kind of software and once expanded, option to close it show it in a resized format like the below video

https://vimeo.com/214951018

Comment: the link was broken, maybe your boss deleted it?

Comment: i fixed it, its privacy was set to me only

Answer (score 0):

You can use  jQuery Image Gallery Slideshow and on click of image u can make use of css to expand images

Comment: so there is no such plugin, is it

Comment: there are so many plugins but browser compatibility will be less                         use below link which can help u to understand.    https://codyhouse.co/demo/expandable-image-gallery/index.html#0